# Loop through a string to find the odd numbers VB

Tags: vba, loops

I am looping through a card number finding all the odd numbers and multiplying them by the card digits. Its kind of hard to explain. I am having trouble multiplying the odd number and the card number. Here's an example my teacher gave me. You multiply card number 1 and and odd number 1 and so forth. I am not getting any errors, it just kind of freezes.

```
Sums        
Card #:     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1   2   3   4   5   6           
Multiples   1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8               
Evens:      2       4       6       8       0       2       4       6   32  =Sum 1  
Odds:       1       6       15      28      45      6       21      40  162 =Sum 2
```

```
Sum 3:  194                                                             
194 =Sum 3  
Step 4: =1+9+4 = 14                                                                     
= 1 + 4 = 5 = check digit
```

```
Public Class Payment
Private Sub OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    Dim Sum1 = 0
    Dim Sum2 = 0
    Dim Sum3 = 0
    Dim ready As Boolean
    Dim ccnumb = CardNumber.Text
    Format(CardNumber.Text, "################")
    Dim exp = Mid(ExpDate.Text, 1, 3)
    Dim checkdigit = 0
    If FullName.TextLength = 0 Or cardtype.Text.Length = 0 And ccnumb.Length <= 16 Or exp.Length = 2 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter all credit card information before proceeding.")
        ready = False
    Else ready = True
    End If
    If ready = True Then
        For Each num As Char In ccnumb
            If CInt(CStr(num)) Mod 2 <> 0 Then
                Sum1 += CInt(CStr(num)) * CInt(CStr(num)) Mod 2 <> 0
            Else
                Sum2 += CInt(CStr(num))
            End If
        Next

        Sum3 = Sum1 + Sum2
        Do While Sum3 > 10
            For j = 0 To Sum3.ToString.Length - 1
                For k = 1 To Sum3.ToString.Length - 1
                    Sum3 = j + k
                Next
            Next
        Loop
        Do While exp.Length > 1
            checkdigit = Mid(ExpDate.Text, 1, 1) + Mid(ExpDate.Text, 1, 2)
        Loop
        If Sum3 = checkdigit Then
            MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! Your payment was successful.")
            CustInv.Show()
        Else MessageBox.Show("The checkdigit," & Space(1) & Sum3 & Space(1) & "does not match the month code," & Space(1) & checkdigit & "." & Space(1) & "Please reenter your card information.")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this any language in particular; if so, what?

Comment: I am using Visual Baiscs

Answer (score 1):

"it kind of freezes" is lay speak for "my code enters an [infinite loop](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop)".

This looks suspicious:

```
Do While Sum3 > 10
    For j = 0 To Sum3.ToString.Length - 1
         For k = 1 To Sum3.ToString.Length - 1
             Sum3 = j + k
         Next
    Next
Loop
```

To enter the loop, `Sum3` must be greater than 10. For the loop to exit, `Sum3` must not be greater than 10, but your code only *increments* `Sum3`, so `Sum3` can only stay greater than 10.

This means that once entered, this loop is infinite.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I am trying to add the numbers of sum3 until they its just one digit. Say sum3 is 45 or 100, you add 4+5 or 1+0+0 to get the check digit. How would I fix it so its not a infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

If changing outer loop to inside loop doesn't help you

Try this

```
Do While Sum3 > 10 and j < sum3        ' adding j < sum3 might stop the loop
    For j = 0 To Sum3.ToString.Length - 1
         For k = 1 To Sum3.ToString.Length - 1
             Sum3 = j + k
         Next
    Next
Loop
```